# When a thread is not in (Runnable) state while active

Tags: arraylist, thread-safety, copyonwritearraylist

I hope you are all doing well. So coming to the question. I have this part of a code :

```
private static ArrayList<String> primelist = new ArrayList<>();
static void addToList(String list_elm) {
    primelist.add(list_elm);
}
```

Basically this list is being accessed concurrently by multiple number of threads I have created in the full code (below), and these are responsible for making some calculations and return the result which is then going to be added to this `primelist` by calling upon the method `addToList(String list_elm)`.

However, after all of the threads are put to terminated (i.e: finished their job), there exist some null values in `primelist`. So after some research, it turned out that ArrayList is not a thread-safe class and consequently its methods. I want to ask the following (perhaps deep) question:

Would the thread be put into (waiting // timed waiting) while its executing a line of code.., that is to say it is calling upon the method `addToList(String list_elm)` and it reached the line `primelist.add(list_elm);` but while adding the element it just happened to stop!

If not could you please clarify my confusion regarding (especially) the ArrayList case. (( basically what is going on? ^^ ))

Full code:

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;    
    import java.util.Iterator;

    public class CreatingAThreadThree
    {
    private static ArrayList<String> primelist = new ArrayList<>();
    static void addToList(String list_elm)
    {
        primelist.add(list_elm);
    }
    static ArrayList<String> getListReference(){
        return primelist;
    } 
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        for(long x = 6223372036854775899L; x<=(6223372036854775999L); x+=2)
        {
            new Thread (new MyCalcRunnable(x)).start();             
        }
        for(long x = 9223372036854774703L; x<=9223372036854774789L; x+=2 )
        {
            new MyCalcThread(x, "myChildThread"+x);             
        }

        Thread mainThread = Thread.currentThread();
        int spinner =0;
        char animation = ' ';
        System.out.println("Total number of active threads: " + Thread.activeCount());
        System.out.print("Calculating primes: ");
        while(Thread.activeCount()   >1)
        {
            spinner ++;
            switch(spinner)
            {
            case 1:
                animation = '|';
                break;
            case 2:
                animation = '/';
                break;
            case 3:
                animation = '-';
                break;
            case 4:
                animation = '\\';
                spinner = 0;
                break;
            }
            System.out.print("\b" + animation);
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(200);
            }catch(InterruptedException ex)
            {
            }           
        }
        System.out.println("Total number of active threads: " + Thread.activeCount());
        System.out.println("Results List:");
        Iterator<?> iterator = (getListReference().iterator());
        while(iterator.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.println(iterator.next());
        }
    }
    }

    class MyCalcThread extends Thread
    {
    private long numberToFactor = 0;
    MyCalcThread(long numberToFactor, String name)
    {
        super(name);
        this.numberToFactor = numberToFactor;
        start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        CreatingAThreadThree.addToList(new PrimeStuff().isItPrime(this.numberToFactor));
    }
    }

    class MyCalcRunnable implements Runnable
    {
    private long numberToFactor = 0;
    MyCalcRunnable(long numberToFactor)
    {
        this.numberToFactor = numberToFactor;   
    }
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
    CreatingAThreadThree.addToList(new PrimeStuff().isItPrime(this.numberToFactor));
    }
    }

    class PrimeStuff
    {
    String isItPrime(long numberToFactor)
    {
        if(numberToFactor % 2 == 0)         
            return (numberToFactor +"is Not prime....divisible by 2");

        long squareRoot = (long)(Math.sqrt(numberToFactor));
        for(long i=3; i<squareRoot; i++)
        {
            if(numberToFactor % i == 0)
            {
                return (numberToFactor +"is Not prime....first divisible by " +                  i);    
            }
        }
        return (numberToFactor + " is Prime!!");
    }
    }
```

Comment: One note here: you want to read about java coding style conventions. For example, you dont use "_" in normal variable names; those are for SOME_CONSTANT only.

Comment: As far as I know that the "_" is in by convention used in constants when also all the letters are uppercase.., which is not the case in my code.

Comment: What I mean is: _ is ONLY used for constants. It is not used like your list_elem for example.

Comment: @Xinchao Refactoring code in a *question* is a **really** bad idea, as it can confuse both the OP and answers, + future readers. If you want a canonical [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I would suggest asking a new question as a lesser evil (one of the questions would then be a duplicate.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are focusing on the wrong question; meaning: invest your time into fixing your broken code.

When you have multiple threads accessing the same shared, **unprotected** data; all kinds of things can happen.

Plus: just changing the type of the list you are using *might* not be enough. You see, that CopyOnWrite list guarantees "thread safety" for single operations. But when you have things like

```
if (someList.size() > 1) {
  do something with your list
```

is still not safe; even when using the CopyOnWrite list - because there are two calls on the list; and the list could change between the first and the second call; when some other thread changes the list in the meantime.

Long story short: one solution is using `synchronized` on those of **your** methods that you do **not** want to run in parallel.

In other words: add the protection you need; instead of confusing yourself by understanding the details of the thread status model - that part will not help you to write correct code.

Given your comment: you try to solve this on a very "low" level. You think you have to understand threads states, and waiting conditions, and so on to come to a "good" solution. But that isn't an efficient approach; especially when you are newbie and learning these things.

First you should worry about coming to a **correct** solution. And then you can go forward and enhance it; for example by doing different experiments. And in that sense, you should understand: in real multi-threading, we usually try to *abstract* from such low level details. Instead, we even introduce **additional** layers, such as [Executors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html) for example.

What I am trying to tell you: looking into low level details is most likely not going to help you, but overburden you at this point.

Comment: thx, I do appreciate your attempt to help me in this regard. However, you see I guess in that code the only problem is in invoking the method to add elements to the ArrayList. As for the other operations they all must execute after one thread is alive which is basically the main thread (this is according to the limit of my current knowledge) unless otherwise there is more to say here. I'd like finally to say that I wanted to understand the thread model so that I predict where I have to make the protection I need for a better cleaner and safer(just-as-needed (no more no less)) code.

Comment: Thank you again for helping me out. I've actually studied most of these basic topics before.., now I'm trying to review and dive a little deeply into the subject..., as for the code above.., this is not a perfect one, and I did realize how to solve this problem.., but I thought it is a good idea to know better about what is going on behind the scenes. I'm definitely still a newbie ^^ after all, but as for these out-of-convention named variables I just did not pay that attention to!.., thank you for your great pieces of advice.

Comment: Excuse me for the inconvenience regarding the green tick.., I had a problem with my computer.., you definitely deserve it. but I would like to be frank with you.., I do expect an answer that is direct to the question.., extra points would be added later for the caring or personal opinions regarding the question or the one who asked. So by convention your answer is the best so far ^^.

Answer (score 0):

The race condition can happen anywhere, not just within the code you write, but also within the implementation of ArrayList.

Adding to ArrayList even in its simplest form will involve these actions:

1. read the `size` variable
2. write the data to `elementData[size]`
3. increment the `size` variable

When adding operation increases the size to be larger than the length of `elementData`, resizing will also occur:

1. make a new array of 1.5 times as large as the current `elementData`
2. copy the values from `elementData` into the new array
3. assign the new array to `elementData`
4. write the data to `elementData[size]`
5. increment the `size` variable

In your case, if you get null added to the list, chances are that two threads are trying to resize the array at the same time. Let's say at the moment your list has 10 elements. And the `elementData` is of length 10. So adding the 11th value will resize the `elementData`

1. Thread 1 creates a new array X of length 15
2. Thread 1 copies the data from `elementData` to the new array
3. Thread 2 creates a new array Y of length 15
4. Thread 2 copies the data from `elementData` to the new array
5. Thread 1 assigns X to `elementData`
6. Thread 1 writes value to `elementData[10]`
7. Thread 1 increments `size` to 11
8. **Thread 2 assigns Y to `elementData`**
9. Thread 2 writes value to `elementData[11]`
10. Thread 2 increments `size` to 12
11. elementData[10] as a result will be null

What happened in step 8 is that Thread 2 overwrites the `elementData` changed by Thread 1, and therefore elementData[10] (written by Thread 1) is lost.